# Change language in google maps v2 api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to change the google map language displayed in my android app? My app uses api v2. I have changed the locale via settings to different languages but it doesn't have any effect on the maps displayed in my app.

When i use google maps app , it displays the translations correctly. I think it uses api v3.

Comment: "I have changed the locale to different languages" -- via the Settings app, via `Locale.setLocale()`, or something else?

Comment: @CommonsWare via settings.

Comment: Hmmm... I would have expected that to work. I could see where `setLocale()` might not, since the map rendering is being done by a foreign process.

Comment: @RachelGallen I am not sure how your link is beneficial for me to solve my issue.

Comment: Just change the locale on the device. If translations are available, they will be shown automatically.