# How to change Google Map v2 api language to Hebrew?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, localization, google-maps-android-api-2

I am new to Android development.

In Google Maps Android API V2 how do I make the streets name to display in another language like Hebrew?

Comment: Check this posting. may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24531604/change-language-in-google-maps-v2-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the device's default language setting to Hebrew may achieve this.